# What is the use of a single ultrasonic signal?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, piece-information, piece-usage, sensor-ultrasonic

The EV3 ultrasonic sensor has an advanced mode that includes an option to use single or continuous sensing as described in the Help page:

> You can choose whether the sensor sends a single ultrasonic signal or continuous signals with the Measuring Mode input.

What is the purpose of a single ultrasonic signal? In what situations may the sensor need to send a single signal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced mode in EV3 ultrasonic sensor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/advanced-mode-in-ev3-ultrasonic-sensor)

Comment: You want run dark and then communicate "Hunt for Red October" style with a single pulse ;)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an EV3 expert, but my understanding is that continuous mode stores results into a buffer that can be read nearly instantly. Single mode will need to wait to hear a ping back before reporting results.

Continuous mode will give you a faster response time. However, if you are using a number of ultrasonic sensors, they may interfere with one another, and using single mode should prevent this.

Comment: [David Lechner has come to the same conclusion](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev-lang-python/issues/364#issuecomment-332401083): it is intended to avoid cross-talk between two or more ultrasonic sensors.